# Equivalence in ReactiveUI?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactiveui

I have this property **inside a ReactiveObject**:

```
bool IsValid => Children.All(child => child.IsValid);
```

The problem is that, of course, it doesn't raise any change notification when children are modified (their "IsValid" property).

How is this done the right way in ReactiveUI?

**NOTE:**

- Child is a ReactiveObject, too.
- I can modify both classes, parent
  and children, to meet RxUI precepts and guidelines with no
  restriction.

Comment: Does `child.IsValid` raise `PropertyChanged` events?

Comment: Child is a ReactiveObject. I can model it freely. How could I propagate changes from the child to the parent? The semantics of what I want to do is: "I'm valid if my children are valid."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***ObservableAsPropertyHelper< bool >*** is what you need, if your *Children* property is a reactive list you can merge *Changed* and *ItemChanged* observables and have something like:

```
public class MyViewModel : ReactiveObject
    {
        private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> _isValidPropertyHelper;

        public MyViewModel()
        {
            var listChanged = Children.Changed.Select(_ => Unit.Default);
            var childrenChanged = Children.ItemChanged.Select(_ => Unit.Default);
            _isValidPropertyHelper = listChanged.Merge(childrenChanged)
                                                .Select(_ => Children.All(c => c.IsValid))
                                                .ToProperty(this, model => model.IsValid);

        }
        public bool IsValid
        {
            get { return _isValidPropertyHelper.Value; }
        }

        public ReactiveList<Item> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: This assumes that OP wants to update `MyViewModel.IsValid` only when a child is added/removed/replaced, not when `child.IsValid` changes. I'm not sure if that was his intent.

Comment: @ds-b I'm sorry, but I feels your answer doesn't work :(

Comment: I think if Children is a `ReactiveList` you will need to set `Children.ChangeTrackingEnabled = true` for this to work.